# How to get all unit vectors of 4 dimension with all entries $\pm 1/2$ using only Hadamard and SWAP transformations

Tags: quantum-state, hadamard

We consider the group of unitary matrices, $G$ that generated by the Hadamard matrices $H_2$,$H_4$ and and SWAP matrix (i.e., permutation matrices that swap two qubit lines). Consider all unit vectors whose components are all either 1/2 or -1/2 (that is, $2^4=16$ vectors).
My question is: ***Can we show that all unit vectors can be obtained from one another by using only the transformations in $G$*?**

NOTE: I think of group $G$ with 8 possible matrices that can represent combinations of Hadamard and SWAP transformations such as $H_4=H_2\otimes H_2$, $H_2 \otimes I$, $I \otimes H_2$, $SWAP$, $(H_2 \otimes H_2)SWAP$, $(H_2\otimes I)SWAP$, $(I\otimes H_2)SWAP$ and $I \otimes I$ (note that SWAP Matrix is commutative). But, I cannot infer that we can only use representation matrices corresponding to the transformations in group G to all unit vectors of dimension 4 that have $\pm 1/2$ as entries can be obtained from one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot. Consider the state with coefficients $(1,1,1,-1)/2$. This is a maximally entangled state (you can write it as $|0+\rangle+|1-\rangle$). This means that you need an entangling gate to generate it from an initially separable state such as $|++\rangle$, and you don't have an entangling gate in $G$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right!